# Show how many words repeated in a text area

Tags: javascript, dom, textarea, repeat

I extract the word count with this:

```
var sim = /\s+/gi;                                                     

var words= parag.value.trim().replace(sim, ' ').split(' ').length;
```

And I want to show repeated words, how I can?

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet will give you an array of repeated words in a text:

```
var text = "this is this and that was that";
var frequency = text.split(' ').reduce(function(previous, current) {
    if (!previous.hasOwnProperty(current)) {
        previous[current] = 0;
    }
    previous[current] += 1;
    return previous;
}, {});

var repeatedWords = Object.keys(frequency).filter(function(element) {
    return frequency[element] > 1;
});

console.log(repeatedWords);
// => ["this", "that"]
```

1. Split the text into tokens.
2. Reduce array to an object.
3. Initialize an empty object.
4. If token does not exist, set it to 0.
5. Increment token count by one.
6. Go through every token.
7. Filter tokens that have a count higher than 1.

Comment: Well done Amberlamps, may I ask you how would you add a filtrer that loops trough strings with lenght bigger > 5 symbols? thanks

Comment: Sure. If you only want to concentrate on words bigger than 5 letters, replace this `frequency[element] > 1` with this `frequency[element] > 1 && element.length > 5`.